# With Qt, how to check if stdin is empty?

Tags: qt, stdin

I have a Qt program that processes stdin data like this:

```
QTextStream qtin(stdin);
QString stdindata = qtin.readAll();
QByteArray ba;
ba = stdindata.toUtf8();
QJsonDocument exJSONDoc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(ba));
QJsonObject extRoot;
extRoot = exJSONDoc.object();
QStringList keys;
keys = extRoot.keys();
for (int n=0; n <= keys.count()-1; n++)
{
    qDebug() << extRoot.value(keys[n]).toString();
}
```

It works when I call my program like this:

```
myprogram < ./data.json
```

But if I call it without any "<" it hangs in `qtin.readAll()`.

How can I check with Qt if the stdin is empty?

Comment: On what operating system? And what *exactly* do you mean by "stdin is empty"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>(I am assuming a Linux -or at least POSIX- operating system)</sup>

```
QTextStream qtin(stdin);
QString stdindata = qtin.readAll();
```

This would read stdin till end-of-file is reached. So works with a redirected input like

```
myprogram < ./data.json
```

> But if I call it without any "<" it hangs ...

But then (that is, if you run `myprogram` alone) *stdin* is *not* empty. It is the same as your shell's stdin. and your program, being the foreground job, is waiting for input on the terminal you are typing (see also [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html)). Try (in that case) typing some input on the terminal (which you could end with <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> to make an end-of-file condition). Read about [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)) and the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and see also [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html).

Perhaps you could detect that situation with e.g. [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) on `STDIN_FILENO`. But that won't detect a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) like

```
tail -55 somefile | myprogram
```

You need to define what an empty stdin is for you. I have no idea what that means to you, and I would instead think of `myprogram < /dev/null` (see [null(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html)) as the way to get an empty stdin.

Perhaps you should design  `myprogram` so that some program 
option (perhaps `--ignore-stdin`) is avoiding any read from stdin.

Answer (score 2):

Problem here is readAll. See [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#readAll):

> Reads the entire content of the stream, and returns it as a **QString**.
>   Avoid this function when working on large files, as it will consume a
>   significant amount of memory.

So it reads `stdin` until it encounters end of file and since `stdin` is associated with console you have to signal end of file. Usually it is Ctrl-D and press enter.

It is more probable you what to read `stdin` line by line.
To alow user text editing console transfers data to standard input of the application only line by line. This was designed like this ages ago when computer had only a printer as user interface (no screen).

---

Now question is how to read JSon form `stdin` console connected with console without end of file information?

I would use some SAX parser, but this would be to complicated for you.
So is there another way to detect end of JSon?

You can try this approach (this is basic idea, not final solution, so it has couple shortcomings):

```
QFile file(stdin);
QByteArray data = file.peak(largeNumber);
QJsonParseError error;
QJSonDocument doc = QJSonDocument::fromJson(data, &error);
while (!doc.isValid() && JSonNotTerminatedError(error.error))
{
    // TODO: wait for new data - it would be best to use readyRead signal
    doc = QJSonDocument::fromJson(data, &error);
}
```

Where `JSonNotTerminatedError` returns true for respective [QJsonParseError::ParseError values](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonparseerror.html#ParseError-enum) (see linked documentation) which are related with unterminated JSon data.

Now I see `QFile` doesn't have required constructor, but main concept should be clear. Read data from `stdin` and check if it is a valid JSon document.

Comment: Main aim of answer was to point out source of problem (nature of console connected to `stdin`). Since Qt delivers only DOM JSon parser, you have to find way to discover end of JSon. Adding to the project a SAX parser will be overkill for you.